# Custom attributes for encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

Is it possible to create a custom attribute so that whenever that attribute is placed over a property it automatically get encrypted.

```
class encrypt
{
 [encryption]
 string password{get;set;}

}
```

this password field will be coming from a form input so what ever user gives the input it should get encrypted automatically if this attribute is placed over that property.

Answer (score 1):

When a form is submitted, the value of input fields will be sent in plain text. Encrypting in javascript before submitting is pointless because you will need to expose the secret key to the client. Your best bet is to use HTTPS for those kind of sensitive information such as passwords. To avoid them being sent in clear text over the wire between the client and the server, just make sure that the form is submitted over SSL.